# What is stored in Options|Advanced|PostgreSQL|connections|dbname|keys group in QGIS 3?

Tags: postgresql, qgis-3

Since QGIS 3 in the Options|Advanced|PostgreSQL path referred to in the title there is a new group 'keys' as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

In old QGIS 2.X:

[image]

What kind of information is stored in this 'keys' group and what do the Types / Values mean?

Comment: what exact version of QGIS, are you on 3.6? I still see the 2.x style settings in 3.4 (Mac). It might also be authentication related?

Comment: I observe this in each of the QGIS 3 versions (3.4.5LTR, 3.6.0 and 3.7.0) on Win10. It seems independent of the authentication method used (authconfig vs. basic authentication).